# Authorize Google App Script before needed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, authorization

I wrote a Google App Script to be executed in Chrome by an extension without user interaction.
How can I let the user authorize it from the extension's options page?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the script is published to run as the user. If so just provide a link to the script from your options page with a parameter so you know it comes from there.

Comment: That's my backup plan, but I would like the link to open the popup window right away instead of showing "This app needs authorization to run." and a "Continue" button.

Comment: you cant do that because of browser policies. there must be a user action for the browser to open a popup. this applies to any browser code, not just gas.

Comment: I understand, but clicking a link or button in the options page would be user action, I hope.

Comment: yea it will work but only if you open it in a new tab. that tab will take care of showing the auth popups